# for loop with .find ( )

Tags: python, if-statement, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to programming and I have been studying through FreeCodeCamp for a couple of weeks. I was reviewing a code available on their website and I have two questions.

1. Why is it necessary to shuffle the variable allLinks?
2. What does `if link ['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1` really check?

I really appreciate your help.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import random

response = requests.get(
    url="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping",
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find(id="firstHeading")
print(title.content)

# Get all the links
allLinks = soup.find(id="bodyContent").find_all("a")
random.shuffle(allLinks)   
linkToScrape = 0

for link in allLinks:
    # We are only interested in other wiki articles
    if link['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1: 
        continue

    # Use this link to scrape
    linkToScrape = link
    break

print(linkToScrape)
```

Here is the output:

```
<a href="/wiki/Eventbrite" title="Eventbrite">Eventbrite, Inc.</a>
```

Comment: What have you tried to answer your own questions? For example, what do you notice about the list before and after it's shuffled? Have you checked to see what the links are that return `-1` for the `.find()` vs those that return something else?

Comment: Hi Martineau. Yeah, actually I did many things, changed the code and printed it in different ways, but unfortunately I couldn't understand 1) what was the thing with shuffle (I know what it does, but I didn't understand how it was applicable to this code)  2) I didn't understand the if [href], once I thought it was not possible to give str as index, but now I suppose this is possible when using beautifulsoup. I'm still learning, but believe me, before I come here I always try to find my own solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to first explain question 2 and describe what the code is doing.

Recall that find() returns returns the index of the first occurence of the substring or  -1 if it can't find the desired substring. So `if link ['href'].find("/wiki/") == -1`checks if the substring "/wiki/" is found in the string `link ['href']`. It executes the `continue` if the reference link does not contain "/wiki/". So the loop will continue through the links until it finds a link that contains /wiki/ or until it goes through all the links. Hence the value of linkToScrape at the end of the loop will be the first link containing /wiki/ or 0 if no links contain it.

Now for the first question, the shuffle is necessary for the code to do what it does, which is printing a random wikipidia article linked within the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping. Without the shuffling the code would instead always print the first wiki article linked within the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping.

Note: The intention expressed in the comments is to find only wiki articles, but a link such as https://google.com/wiki/ will also be printed without being a wiki article.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation was perfect! Have a great week!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the documentation for `.find()` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find

Basically, `haystack.find(needle) == -1` is a roundabout way of saying `needle not in haystack`.

The point of calling `random.shuffle()` is that the author of this code evidently wanted to select a link from the page at random rather than using, say, the first one or the last one.